# PDO SSL - Strange Behavior

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, pdo

I am attempting to connect to a MySQL database on Amazon RDS using PHP PDO with the provided client certificate. The actual cert is located here:
 `var/www/includes/database/certs/cert.pem`

I am setting the SSL attributes as such:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=example.com;dbname=example', username, password,  array(
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT=>'/var/www/includes/database/certs/cert.pem'
              ));

var_dump($db->query("SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';")->fetchAll());

/* Output */
#array(1) {
#  [0]=>
#  array(4) {
#    ["Variable_name"]=>
#    string(10) "Ssl_cipher"
#    [0]=>
#   string(10) "Ssl_cipher"
#    ["Value"]=>
#    string(10) "AES256-SHA"
#    [1]=>
#    string(10) "AES256-SHA"
#  }
#}
```

Which makes it seem like its working. *However*, if I change the attribute to an incorrect path, such as `/var/www/includes/database/a`, I still get the same exact cipher output, and no errors. Very strange. Now the directory `/var/www/includes/database/a` does not exist. When I make that folder `a`, and run the script above, I finally get the SSL error:

```
#PHP Warning:  PDO::__construct(): Unable to set local cert chain file `/var/www/includes/database/a'; Check that your cafile/capath settings include details of your certificate and its issuer in /var/www/includes/database/db_connect.php on line 11
#PHP Warning:  PDO::__construct(): failed to create an SSL handle in /var/www/includes/database/db_connect.php on line 11
#PHP Warning:  PDO::__construct(): Cannot connect to MySQL by using SSL in /var/www/includes/database/db_connect.php on line 11
#PHP Warning:  PDO::__construct(): [2002]  (trying to connect via tcp://example.com:3306) in /var/www/includes/database/db_connect.php on line 11
#PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] ' in /var/www/includes/database/db_connect.php:11
```

- Why did it appear that it correctly connected with a nonexistent directory?
- Why did it only throw the error after I actually made that directory?
- How can I be sure that PDO is connecting via SSL *(besides wireshark)*?

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd supply some input to this as I had the same SSL error messages at the bottom when trying to connect MySQL client from Ubuntu linux to an AWS RDS MySQL instance. I copied the instructions from the AWS page, and a couple of things to say about it:

Your question: "How can I be sure that PDO is connecting via SSL (besides wireshark)?"

You can set the requirement on the MySQL user accounts, as such:

GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;

If you're using default PDO connection instructions, be sure that you don't include all of the key/cert/ca statements. For AWS RDS MySQL, you only use the CA statement (similar to what you would do if using the Sequel Pro GUI):

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=ssldb',
    'username',
    'password',
    array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA    =>'/etc/mysql/ssl/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'
    )
);
```

Comment: Great to know how to ensure secure connection to MySQL via the user account. This question is no longer relevent to me, but I still find it strange how it was operating regarding an invalid cert path.